# How to properly sanitize user input in WordPress search form: get_search_query()

Tags: wordpress, sanitization, search-form

I am attempting to sanitize user input for a search form that I am building in WordPress (in `searchform.php` file).

I used a built-in WordPress function, [sanitize_text_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/):

```
function wpdocs_my_search_form( $form ) {
    $search_query = sanitize_text_field( get_search_query() );
    
    $form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __( 'Search for:' ) . '</label>
    <input type="text" value="' . $search_query . '" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__( 'Search' ) .'" />
    </div>
    </form>';

    return $form;
}
add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'wpdocs_my_search_form' );
```

This however, is still not properly sanitizing input such as `<script></script>`

I also attempted to add additional code to detect if it has been submitted however, that is also not working. I would appreciate any direction/pointers.

Comment: What is it doing wrong and what do you need it to do?

Comment: [get_search_query()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_query/#description) is already cleaning up all the bad stuff for you though: "The search query string is passed through [esc_attr()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) to ensure that it is safe for placing in an HTML attribute."

Comment: @JayDev95, I would like it to remove invalid (potentially dangerous characters) such as <> i.e. <script> should be sanitized to just script

Comment: @cabrerahector I believe there are still instances where putting in an input such as <script> triggers a firewall on the website. Ideally, I would like the search_query to be sanitized beforehand instead